# Share using Facebook Application

Tags: ios, facebook

Right now I'm using a [Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/ios/) to share posts from my application. The problem is that this sdk pops up a webview inside my app and asks the user to log in. There has to be a better way.

Can I send the share information to the facebook app on the users device (If they have it installed)? Or at least leverage the facebook app to check credentials? If people have to sign in to share, they probably won't do it..

Answer (score 2):

The latest [Facebook SDK 3.5](https://developers.facebook.com/ios/features/whats-new-ios-sdk-3.5/) includes a native share dialog. If you follow the authentication workflow according do the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/) and the phone is on iOS 6.0 you should not get a UIWebView during authentication, instead you will get a UIAlertView.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook login process would use WebView only in a few cases. Some of them are:
1) You are asking it to do so explicitly, by using `- (void)openWithBehavior:(FBSessionLoginBehavior)behavior completionHandler:(FBSessionStateHandler)handler;` which, I think, is not your case.
2) If there is no Facebook app installed on the device, FB SDK falls back to using WebView login window.
3) Probably, this is your case. If you are requesting publish permissions on the first attempt to open FB session, FB SDK will also fall back to old login flow envolving WebView. In the new login flow, FB session is supposed to be open with read permissions first (in that case, FB will use fast app switching or native iOS FB login):
`+ (BOOL)openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:(NSArray*)readPermissions allowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI completionHandler:(FBSessionStateHandler)handler;`

Then, you should ask additional publish permissions from the user:
`- (void)requestNewPublishPermissions:(NSArray*)writePermissions defaultAudience:(FBSessionDefaultAudience)defaultAudience completionHandler:(FBSessionRequestPermissionResultHandler)handler;`

That way, user will not need to log in (if he is logged in FB app already), but there will be inconvenience of double switching from your app to FB (though it works rather fast lately).
I was looking for a cleaner way to get publish permissions with FB Single Sign On on the first call, but unfortunately didn't find anything working yet.